# react-loading-skeleton keeps on loading

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to redo my personal site, I'm stuck here trying to use react-loading-skeleton. Here's my code:

```
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { isLoading: true }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }

  render() {

    let button;

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      button = 'Hi, there!';
    } else {
      button = <Skeleton />;
    }
```

I want the text to load when the state is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do your job:

```
 state={
        isLoading:true
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({isLoading:false})
        }, 1000);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.isLoading?(
                <div>Loading...</div>
            ):(
                <div>
                    Welcome
                </div>
            )
        )
    }
```